# Laravel: ordering a many-many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many-many relation between Ingredient and Recipe, with a pivot table (ingredient_recipe).

I'd like to get ingredients ordered by how many recipes have them. Example, if I use salt in 2 recipes and meat in 3 recipes, I'll have meat before salt.

This is what I have. It works but it doesn't order correctly, even though the resulting query executed directly on my DB works as expected, so Laravel is doing something internally, I guess.

```
//Ingredient model
public function recipesCount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe')->selectRaw('count(ingredient_recipe.recipe_id) as aggregate')->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')->groupBy('ingredient_recipe.ingredient_id');
}

public function getRecipesCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('recipesCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('recipesCount');

    $related = $this->getRelation('recipesCount')->first();

    return ($related) ? $related->aggregate : 0;
}

//controller
$ingredients = Ingredient::with('recipesCount')->whereHas('recipes', function($q)
                    {
                            $q->where('user_id', Auth::id());

                    })->take(5)->get();

//outputting the last query here and executing it on my db returns correctly ordered results.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to `order by` related table you need `join`. There's no way to achieve that with eager loading whatsoever.

```
Ingredient::with('recipesCount')
    ->join('ingredient_recipe as ir', 'ir.ingredient_id', '=', 'ingredients.id')
    ->join('recipes as r', function ($j) {
        $j->on('r.id', '=', 'ir.recipe_id')
          ->where('r.user_id', '=', Auth::id());
    })
    ->orderByRaw('count(r.id) desc')
    ->groupBy('ingredients.id')
    ->take(5)
    ->get(['ingredients.*']);
```

There's no need for `whereHas` anymore, for `inner joins` will do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me. I thought I didn't need "with('recipesCount')" anymore, but I still do, although I suspect I can somehow add it to the SELECT in that same query, but I need to investigate.

Comment: Feel free to remove `with('recipesCount')` and instead `select count(r.id) as recipesNumber` - just don't use the same name `recipesCount`, because calling it would result in running relation query anyway.